# JavaScript based application work flow -- how does it work?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I often find myself wondering what is the best way to do a JavaScript based web application. The server may be PHP, Perl or whatever -- but when the client-side is ExtJS or something similar, how do you construct your application? What is the work flow exactly?

For example, how is the authentication handled? In a current application I am developing, I have an ExtJS viewport with a login screen component in it, when the app is being run, it does an AJAX callback to the server to find out whether it's authenticated. If not, I show the login part -- else I show the application viewport. And then depending on the URI hash (e.g. #page=settings&subpage=ui) I run automatically certain components and events in my system.

And what do you do with the back-button. Currently I have a timer that checks if the hash has changed, and if so, I run the new action based on the new hash.

I am interested in any application work flow or logic that you have to share with me -- or any resources you got. I feel like JavaScript based application development has not matured enough yet, because there is almost zero blogs, tutorials, articles, whatsoever talking about this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to leverage some of the capabilities of popular frameworks such as Spring MVC.  Spring has the ability to handle workflows.

[Spring Webflow Introduction](http://www.springsource.org/webflow)

The whole point of a web application is to have your business logic happen on the server-side and not the client.  JavaScript can be pesky enough to debug on it's own.  Things that are business-logic heavy is best encapsulated in it's own tier of your application.

Comment: I don't understand your "the whole point of a web app is to have your loginc on the server-side". If you have a web based Photoshop, why would it be necessary to have server-side business logic?

Comment: The server-side business logic for the photoshop example would be for the uploaded images to be associated with your login account.  The photo manipulation tools use a client side framework (FLEX) to interact with the back end.

For your login example, I really think any MVC (Model View Container) framework will provide what you're looking for.

Comment: I will not use FLEX. I do not need a server. I am writing a web based application. I am using ExtJS.